# How to change a single row value in APEX 5.1?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have converted two of my columns into buttons that the user can use to change the row information. They are tied to two processes that should change several values of the same row the user clicked.
[image: Table Sample]

However, I cannot select the specific field in the process and instead update all the values in the column. Is there a way for me to update only certain fields on the same row the user clicked?

This is a silly question, but I am a newbie in a busy department so any help will be thoroughly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your buttons submit the page to invoke the process (you haven't said how they work) you need to set a `REQUEST` value with two pieces of information in it:

1. The action you want performed
2. The key for the row it was clicked on

So your report SQL needs to construct the request value something like:

```
'APPROVE-' || record_id
```

Then the process condition needs to be something like:

```
:REQUEST like 'APPROVE-%'
```

and the process code needs to split the `REQUEST` value apart to extract the record_id value.

Comment: I reckon you mean something like that?

https://imgur.com/a/VKHPHCJ

I call the process through the html code. My specific problem is calling a single column value in the process. I don't know how to reference the value in the button's row.